# How can i add an image to appear behind the border

Tags: html, css

I want an image border like in the code and i want to add an image in it.
How can i achieve that?

```css
.type3 {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: aqua;
    border: 30px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="circleBase type3">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="my-pic.jpg">
</div>
```

ml -->

```
<div class="circleBase type3"></div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image

Comment: I did that but the image is appearing infront of the border and i want it behind the border.

Comment: Can you please illustrate your requirement using a graphic?

Answer (score 0):

Directly you can add border to image itself.

This can be done by two ways:

```
<img src="..." border="1" />
```

or

```
<img style='border:1px solid #000000' src="..." />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<div class="circleBase type3">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="my-pic.jpg">
</div>
```

```css
.type3 {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: aqua;
    border: 30px solid blue;
    -webkit-border-image: url(border.png) 30 round; /* Safari 3.1-5 */
    -o-border-image: url(border.png) 30 round; /* Opera 11-12.1 */
    border-image: url(border.png) 30 round;
}
```

Replace `border.png` with your border image